# Response with status: 0 for URL: null

Tags: service, angular2-services

I have a service that do post.  The service is being hosted in another machine.  When I tried to post using Postman, it works fine.  Now, when I tried to post using my Angular2 app which is run in another machine I got an error "Response with status: 0  for URL: null."  The code in my angular service is as follows:

```
postQuestions() {
    var json = JSON.stringify({
        "TestInfo_FK"  : "612",
        "Resource_FK"  : 0,
        "QuestionNo"   : 22,
        "ContentType"  : "HTML",
        "Content"      : "This is the question from Jason",
        "NoOptions"    : 4,
        "OptionLayout" : "Vertical",
        "Answer"       : "A"
    });


    var url = 'http://my.service.net/api/ONLINE/Question';
    var params = 'json=' + json;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return this._http.post(url, params, {
        headers: headers
    })
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This situation arises when your hosted service is not able to be accessed via cross origin(CORS) .So if u you are accessing Spring Rest service then use @CrossOrigin annotation on service.
OR use
flask-restful to build remote API

from flask_restful.utils import cors
from flask_restful import Api

api = Api(app, decorators=[cors.crossdomain(origin='*')])

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was causing the issue.. Its a server side issue. You need to set the CORS middleware first then the remaining API middlewares.

Please note i am working with Laravel 5.6 + Angular 5

### Wrong Code

`'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ],`

### Currect Code

`'api' => [
            \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings'
        ],`